# Proper configuration for tracking a walk with cordova background geolocation

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to track a walk. I'm doubting what's the best configuration of the plugin considering that I might stop and sit a bench. It can be that I stop for 2 minutes, or for an hour. What is the proper (battery friendly) way to configure this?

The issues I've encountered in my multiple configuration tests:
- I stop for a little bit. Then I appear after a long time in a very distant place.
- When I walk in a straight line I appear jumping from one side of the sidewalk to the other.

I use all the geo submissions to calculate the distance walked (server side). jumping from one side to the other of the sidewalk greatly increases the distance walked.

The "best" configuration I got so far:

```
desiredAccuracy: 0,
distanceFilter: 5,
stationaryRadius: 3,
locationUpdateInterval: 1000,
fastestLocationUpdateInterval: 500,

// Activity Recognition config
activityType: 'Fitness',
activityRecognitionInterval: 1000,
pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically: false,
stopDetectionDelay: 10,
disableStopDetection: true,
stopTimeout: 240,

// Application config
debug: true,
stopOnTerminate: true,
startOnBoot: false,

// HTTP / SQLite config
url: '',
method: 'POST',
autoSync: true,
maxDaysToPersist: 1,
```

I also played around with changePace() but I guess I didn't understand exactly how this one works.

Thank you.

Attachment: screenshot of zigzag walking
[screenshot of zigzag walking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCMz6.png)